# Random forest classifier

Tags: google-earth-engine, random-forest

I set up a script for supervised following the model from the EE tutorial -- Only thing I changed was to substitute Landsat 5 with Sentinel 2. The classifier does not give me any result -- Any idea why or how to fix it?

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([18.31, 20.85]);
var s2 = s2toa.filterBounds(point) //filter all scenes using point geometry from above (i.e. limit to Friuli)
  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', true).limit(300);
var s2Time1 = s2.select('B[2-8]');
var input = ee.Image(s2Time1.first()).clip(studysite);
print(input)
Map.centerObject(studysite, 10);
Map.addLayer(input, {
  min: 750,
  max: 2100,
  bands: ['B8', 'B3', 'B2']
}, 'input image');
var training = basalt_train.merge(Sand_train);
var training = input.sampleRegions({
  collection: training,
  properties: ['class'],
  scale: 30
});
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100).train(training, 'nd'); //set the number of trees in random forest to 100
var classified = input.classify(classifier);
print(classified)
Map.addLayer(classified, {
  min: 0,
  max: 1
}, 'classified image');
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/751ac9cfdb5c33ad5790bf69bae87003

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Coding questions are expected to contain a relevant code fragment which reproduces the problem. A link to another site is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified a non-existing `classProperty` in `train()`. Update it to `class`, and your code works.

```
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100).train(training, 'class'); //set
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6d425e23cef110a1a97e7aac6fcd8ebb

Comment: Thank's very much for the help! Carla.